Is there any WEAR OS smartwatch with a physical button available for coding within third party Apps?
I am a hobbyist writing an App for Wear OS smartwatches and I would very much prefer to use a physical button to perform some of the actions within my app.
However I understand that Wear OS reserves the use of one or two buttons AND also some smartwatch manufacturers reserve other buttons for proprietary functions. Thus it seems to be hard to find a smartwatch with at least one button available for coding.
Of course I have implemented a workaround that uses touch screen, however I would like to find out if there are any smartwatches where at least one button is available, because if there are none I wouldn’t even bother writing the code to use it if available.
Thanks in advance
Angelo
